# Using the printf is giving me unaligned columns

Tags: java, alignment, printf

I'm trying to have my program print out data in a neat format, with data aligned with the columns. I tried using String.format in my toString method for my class, but it's not aligned at all. How should I change it?

```
package p01;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Book
{
DecimalFormat formatter=new DecimalFormat("##0.00");


private int bookNumber;
private String title;
private String author;
private int numberOfPages;
private String ISBN;
private double price;

public Book(int bookNumber, String title, String author, int numberOfPages,String ISBN, double price)
{
    super();
    this.bookNumber = bookNumber;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
    this.price = price;
}

private final int validBookNumber(int bookNumber)
{
    if(bookNumber<0||bookNumber>7)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The book number must be from 1 to 7");
    }
    return bookNumber;
}

private final String validTitle(String title)
{
    if (title==null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The title can't be null");
    }
    title.trim();
    if(title.length()==0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The title can't be blank");
    }
    return title;
}

private final String validAuthor(String author)
{
    if (author==null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The name of the author can't be null");
    }
    author.trim();
    if(author.length()==0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The name of the author can't be blank");
    }
    return author;
}
private final String validISBN(String ISBN)
{
    if (ISBN==null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The ISBN can't be null");
    }
    ISBN.trim();
    if(ISBN.length()==0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The ISBN can't be blank");
    }
    return ISBN;
}
private final int validNumberOfPages(int numberOfPages)
{
    if(numberOfPages<=0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of pages can't be less than 0");
    }
    return numberOfPages;
}
private final double validPrice(double price)
{
    formatter.format(price);
    if(price<=0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The price can't be less than 0");
    }
    return price;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(obj != null && obj instanceof Book)
    {
        Book tempBook=(Book)obj;
        if(ISBN.equalsIgnoreCase(tempBook.ISBN))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public String toString()
{
    String str;
    str=String.format("%-4s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-3s",validBookNumber(bookNumber),validTitle(title),validAuthor(author),
                        validPrice(price), validNumberOfPages(numberOfPages), validISBN(ISBN));//I used the String formatter here
    return str;
}
```

}

```
package p01;
public class MJE_AB_List_Driver01
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MJE_AB_List<Book>myBookList=new MJE_AB_List<Book>();
    Book book1=new Book(1,"To kill a Mocking Bird", "Harper Lee",336,"9780061120084", 16.99);
    Book book2=new Book(2,"Fahrenheit 451", "Ray Bradbury",256," 9781451673319", 15.99);
    Book book3=new Book(3,"1984", "George Orwell",304,"9780452262935", 16.00);
    Book book4=new Book(4,"Fight Club", "Chuck Palahniuk",224,"0-393-03976-5", 14.95);
    Book book5=new Book(5,"Invisible Monsters", "Chuck Palahniuk",304,"9780061120084", 16.99);
    Book book6=new Book(6,"Frankenstein", "Mary Shelly",256,"9781593081157", 6.95);
    Book book7=new Book(7,"The Grapes of Wrath", "John Steinbeck",528,"9780143039433", 17.00);

    myBookList.add(book1);
    myBookList.add(book2);
    displayList(myBookList);




}
public static void displayList(ParticularListInterface list)//This displays the list
{
    String headerString="Index    Book#    Title     Author     Price   Pages   ISBN";
    System.out.println(headerString +"\n");
    for(int index=0;index<list.size(); index++)
    {

        System.out.println(index+ " "+list.get(index));
    }
}

}
```

This is what I get as my output

```
Index    Book#    Title     Author     Price   Pages   ISBN

0 1    To kill a Mocking Bird Harper Lee  16.99       336            9780061120084
1 2    Fahrenheit 451 Ray Bradbury 15.99       256          9781451673319
```

And this is my output after Simon's answer

```
Index    Book#    Title      Author     Price   Pages   ISBN

0  1    To kill a Mocking Bird                                       Harper Lee                16.99       336         9780061120084
1  2    Fahrenheit 451                                               Ray Bradbury              15.99       256          9781451673319
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the title / author values in your data are longer than the space you've allotted in the `String.format()` call.  Increase the length from 11 to a higher value, e.g.:

```
"%-4s %-40s %-25s %-11s %-11s %-3s"
```

Comment: I tried using that, but it was still unaligned after utilizing it. I have what it prints in the problem above

Comment: Now you have a different problem - the header line does not match up.  Use the same String format to print the columns of the header line.

Comment: I have both changed to use the same format, but after book number, none of it is aligned

Comment: My final advice, then, would be to make sure that the column widths are at least long enough to accommodate the header names. (e.g. Change the width of Book# from "%-4s" to "%-6s").  Writing "index" outside of the String.format() also might be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

The width in the format string is the *minumum* number of characters, so values will be padded to be at least that wide, but if they're longer, then the entire value will be output. That is, unless you specify a *maximum* number of characters using the precision value, for example:

```
String.format("%-4s %-11.11s %-11.11s %-11.11s %-11.11s %-3s");
```

That will truncate the 2nd through 5th values to 11 characters. Note however, that it does just that, just chops off the value, so `"To Kill a Mockingbird"` becomes `"To Kill a M"`, which may or may not be what you want. You could either increase the width (as Simon suggests) and precision, or do the truncation yourself and add an ellipsis or something, for example:

```
if (title.length() > 11)
    title = title.substring(0, 10) + "\u2026";
```

Comment: I've tried looking for info on how to increase the width, but none of it has been clear to me

Comment: The width in the format? That's just the first number after the % and flags (and argument number if you had one of those), so the 11 in your case. Change the 11 to something bigger to increase the minimum width (and fix your header, although I'd modify the header printing to use the same format string, then you don't have to modify one if you modify the other). Here's the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to format string syntax.